# Send a file, a json object and a xml object in one call from javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, http, multipartform-data

The following shows what I want to achieve, but does not work:

BACKEND (Spring):

```
@RequestMapping(
    value="/test", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = { "multipart/mixed", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public String test(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
        @RequestParam("xmlObject") XmlObject xmlObject,
        @RequestPart("jsonObject") JsonObject jsonObject) {
    return "Done";
}
```

FRONTEND:

```
 var multiPart = new FormData();
 multiPart.append('file', file); //file is a File
 multiPart.append('jsonObject', jsonObject); //jsonObject is a jsObject (auto converted by angular to json)
 multiPart.append('xmlObject', xmlString); //xmlString is a xml-string
 //... sendRequest with multiPart as data and Content-Type undefined -> becomes multipart/form-data; with a boundry
```

This gives a exception: `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type '...XmlObject'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [...XmlObject]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found"` or `Required request part 'xmlObject' is not present.`

I tried using Blobs with content-type, but without success.

Also tried changing RequestParam to RequestPart and other values...

How to do this correctly?

(Btw, those calls are all working separately, but I need to bundle them to prevent a inconsistent state)

Comment: what happens if you set 'RequestPart' on all parameters?